# Interpreting Omega coefficients (reliability) from EFA and CFA

Tags: factor-analysis, structural-equation-modeling, reliability, confirmatory-factor, lavaan

I have a dataset with 5 variables and I would like to estimate the reliability of the scale score computed as the linear combination of all items (n = number of items), that is $O = \sum_{i=1}^{n}(X_i)$.

I expect a unidimensional structure, but also correlated errors between variables v3 and v5.

```
> head(dx)
  v1 v2 v3 v4 v5
1  3  3 -3  3 -5
2  5  4 -2  4 -3
3  3  3 -4  3 -2
4  4  3 -3  3 -3
5  3  2 -4  4 -4
6  5  3 -2  5 -1 


> correlation::correlation(dx) %>% summary()
Parameter |      v5 |      v4 |      v3 |      v2
-------------------------------------------------
v1        | 0.28*** | 0.48*** | 0.32*** | 0.42***
v2        | 0.32*** | 0.42*** | 0.31*** |        
v3        | 0.40*** | 0.30*** |         |        
v4        | 0.31*** |         |         |
```

I have tried using packages `psych`, `lavaan` and `semTools` to estimate $\omega$. I need help to understand the output of these analyses.

#### Psych package - EFA

```
> x1 <- omega(m = dx)
> x1
Omega 
Call: omegah(m = m, nfactors = nfactors, fm = fm, key = key, flip = flip, 
    digits = digits, title = title, sl = sl, labels = labels, 
    plot = plot, n.obs = n.obs, rotate = rotate, Phi = Phi, option = option, 
    covar = covar)
Alpha:                 0.73 
G.6:                   0.7 
Omega Hierarchical:    0.59 
Omega H asymptotic:    0.76 
Omega Total            0.77 

Schmid Leiman Factor loadings greater than  0.2 
      g  F1*  F2*  F3*   h2   u2   p2
v1 0.46 0.53           0.51 0.49 0.41
v2 0.48 0.39           0.38 0.62 0.60
v3 0.65                0.43 0.57 0.97
v4 0.45 0.53           0.49 0.51 0.42
v5 0.64                0.43 0.57 0.95

With eigenvalues of:
   g  F1*  F2*  F3* 
1.47 0.72 0.00 0.06 

general/max  2.05   max/min =   368.22
mean percent general =  0.67    with sd =  0.28 and cv of  0.41 
Explained Common Variance of the general factor =  0.65 

The degrees of freedom are -2  and the fit is  0 
The number of observations was  91220  with Chi Square =  0  with prob <  NA
The root mean square of the residuals is  0 
The df corrected root mean square of the residuals is  NA

Compare this with the adequacy of just a general factor and no group factors
The degrees of freedom for just the general factor are 5  and the fit is  0.18 
The number of observations was  91220  with Chi Square =  16409.56  with prob <  0
The root mean square of the residuals is  0.13 
The df corrected root mean square of the residuals is  0.18 

RMSEA index =  0.19  and the 10 % confidence intervals are  0.187 0.192
BIC =  16352.46 

Measures of factor score adequacy             
                                                 g   F1*   F2*   F3*
Correlation of scores with factors            0.81  0.69  0.04  0.30
Multiple R square of scores with factors      0.66  0.48  0.00  0.09
Minimum correlation of factor score estimates 0.32 -0.05 -1.00 -0.81

 Total, General and Subset omega for each subset
                                                 g  F1* F2*  F3*
Omega total for total scores and subscales    0.77 0.71  NA 0.59
Omega general for total scores and subscales  0.59 0.34  NA 0.59
Omega group for total scores and subscales    0.17 0.37  NA 0.00
```

[image]

As I understand, this function does EFA with Schmid-Leiman transformation that extracts the G factor from the previously 3 extracted factors. Did I understand well that:

A. $\omega_h = 0.59$ tells me that 59% of variance in composite score &O& is attributable to the general factor?
B. $\omega_t = 0.77$ tells me that 77% of variance in composite score &O& is attributable to common factor variance (general + other common factors)?

1. In which cases do I report $\omega_h$ and in which $\omega_t$? For me, it would make sense to report only $\omega_h$ because the readers would probably want to know how much of the composite score variance is actually attributed by the G. Or am I mistaken? Which $\omega$ is reported more commonly?
2. When do I use $\omega_hasymptotic$? How do I interpret it and when should I use it?

#### Psych package - CFA

I also tried estimating omega with CFA. When I run `omegaSem`, I get an error

```
> x2 <- omegaSem(m = dx)
Error in str2lang(x) : <text>:2:0: unexpected end of input
1: ~ 
   ^
```

3. Do you know why that happens?

#### Lavaan + semTools - CFA

I also try to manually postulate the model in CFA. Here it makes sense to model the correlated error directly, instead of modeling another factor besides the general one.

```
> m<-'
+ g =~ v1 + v2 + v3 + v4 + v5
+ v3 ~~ v5
+ '
> fit <- cfa(m, data=dx, orthogonal = TRUE)
> summary(fit, fit.measures = T, standardized = T)
lavaan 0.6-7 ended normally after 23 iterations

  Estimator                                         ML
  Optimization method                           NLMINB
  Number of free parameters                         11
                                                      
                                                  Used       Total
  Number of observations                         89798       91220
                                                                  
Model Test User Model:
                                                      
  Test statistic                               613.122
  Degrees of freedom                                 4
  P-value (Chi-square)                           0.000

Model Test Baseline Model:

  Test statistic                             85412.700
  Degrees of freedom                                10
  P-value                                        0.000

User Model versus Baseline Model:

  Comparative Fit Index (CFI)                    0.993
  Tucker-Lewis Index (TLI)                       0.982

Loglikelihood and Information Criteria:

  Loglikelihood user model (H0)            -608146.875
  Loglikelihood unrestricted model (H1)    -607840.314
                                                      
  Akaike (AIC)                             1216315.750
  Bayesian (BIC)                           1216419.209
  Sample-size adjusted Bayesian (BIC)      1216384.251

Root Mean Square Error of Approximation:

  RMSEA                                          0.041
  90 Percent confidence interval - lower         0.038
  90 Percent confidence interval - upper         0.044
  P-value RMSEA <= 0.05                          1.000

Standardized Root Mean Square Residual:

  SRMR                                           0.014

Parameter Estimates:

  Standard errors                             Standard
  Information                                 Expected
  Information saturated (h1) model          Structured

Latent Variables:
                   Estimate  Std.Err  z-value  P(>|z|)   Std.lv  Std.all
  g =~                                                                  
    v1                1.000                               0.680    0.677
    v2                0.882    0.006  137.570    0.000    0.600    0.630
    v3                0.770    0.007  109.383    0.000    0.524    0.466
    v4                0.969    0.007  142.474    0.000    0.659    0.687
    v5                0.741    0.007  105.834    0.000    0.504    0.449

Covariances:
                   Estimate  Std.Err  z-value  P(>|z|)   Std.lv  Std.all
 .v3 ~~                                                                 
   .v5                0.240    0.004   61.537    0.000    0.240    0.240

Variances:
                   Estimate  Std.Err  z-value  P(>|z|)   Std.lv  Std.all
   .v1                0.548    0.004  144.520    0.000    0.548    0.542
   .v2                0.549    0.003  160.026    0.000    0.549    0.604
   .v3                0.988    0.005  189.371    0.000    0.988    0.783
   .v4                0.485    0.003  140.556    0.000    0.485    0.528
   .v5                1.009    0.005  191.263    0.000    1.009    0.799
    g                 0.463    0.005   94.964    0.000    1.000    1.000
```

Then, when calculating $\omega$ I get this:

```
omegaFromSem(fit)
 

 The following analyses were done using the  lavaan  package 

 With only 1 factor specified in the sem model, we can only calculate omega Total.
 You should probably rerun the sem specifying either a bifactor or hierarchical model.

 Omega Total  from a confirmatory model using sem =  0.91 
With loadings of 
     gs   h2   u2   p2
v1 1.00 1.00 0.00 1.00
v2 0.88 0.78 0.22 0.99
v3 0.77 0.59 0.41 1.00
v4 0.97 0.94 0.06 1.00
v5 0.74 0.55 0.45 1.00

With eigenvalues of:
 gs 
3.9 

The degrees of freedom of the confirmatory model are  4  and the fit is  613.1224  with p =  0
general/max  NA   max/min =   NA
mean percent general =  1    with sd =  0 and cv of  0 
Explained Common Variance of the general factor =  1 

To get the standard sem fit statistics, ask for summary on the fitted objectWarning message:
In omegaFromSem(fit) : 
Just one factor defined, therefore, just omega_total is found
> semTools::reliability(fit)
               g
alpha  0.7292208
omega  0.6845254
omega2 0.6845254
omega3 0.6838911
avevar 0.3329071
```

[image]

With `omegaFromSem` function I get $\omega_t=0.91$, which is quite different from the values from the EFA, and $\omega_3 = 0.68$ which is also different from all the values from EFA.

4. How can I interpret $\omega_t$ from `omegaFromSem` function? Why doesn't the function produce $omega_h$ also?
5. Why are omegas from `semTools::reliability` and `psych::omegaFromSem` so different from each other when the model is the same?
6. Why are omegas from `semTools::reliability` and `psych::omegaFromSem`  different from the EFA estimations of $\omega$?

You can see where my confusion comes from. Thanks!